# How to show either a drawer or a bottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a global variable that is true if using Android. The code below doesn't work. How can I decide what widget to display depending on the platform:

rmoMenu is a custom widget that returns a Drawer widget

rmoBottomNavigationBar is a custom widget that returns a BottomNavigationBar widget

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: rmoAppBar(subText: 'My Shifts'),
        if (globals.gblIsAndroid == true) then {
          drawer: rmoMenu()
        } else {
          bottomNavigationBar: rmoBottomNavigationBar(),
        },
        body: ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: rmoAppBar(subText: 'My Shifts'),
  drawer: globals.gblIsAndroid ? rmoMenu() : null,
  bottomNavigationBar: !globals.gblIsAndroid ? rmoBottomNavigationBar() : null,
```